# How can I make an option selected in Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a Product object. Product has 'awards'. award has id and name. If product has already have an award, it should be selected.

```
select#awards(multiple="multiple", name="awards[]")
          for award in awards
            - if ( product.awards.indexOf(award) != -1 )
                option(value=award.id, selected) #{award.name}
            - else
                option(value=award.id) #{award.name}
```

But it is not working. I guess  product.awards.indexOf(award) is not checking the equality of objects. What can I do?

Comment: Shouldn't your loop be `for award in product.awards`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to compare ids:

```
- if ( product.awards.map(function(award) {return award.id}).indexOf(award.id) != -1 )
```